# HSTS Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to implement HSTS on my website and i do have some pages are servered as HTTPS and some pages as HTTP based on the requirements. 
I have given the condition to add HSTS only for the HTTPS page not for the HTTP pages.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme.ToLower() == "https")
{
    response.Headers.Add("Strict-Transport-Security", 
        "max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains; preload");
}
```

It says too many redirects after i added this code.

Please let me know how can i implement the HSTS where we have some pages HTTPS and some pages HTTP.

Comment: This walks through why you are most likely seeing the behavior and strategies around it. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEnableHTTPStrictTransportSecurityHSTSInIIS7.aspx

Comment: Yes i already saw this site and try to implement the same. It behaves the same way too many redirects. Due to http pages i do have some issue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use HSTS if you want some pages to be without https on the same domain. HSTS directs the client (browser) to only access the server via https

More information can be found on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

> When a web application issues HSTS Policy to user agents, conformant
>   user agents behave as follows (RFC 6797):[10]
>
> 1. Automatically turn any insecure links referencing the web application
>      into secure links. (For instance, http://example.com/some/page/ will
>      be modified to https://example.com/some/page/ before accessing the
>      server.)
> 2. If the security of the connection cannot be ensured (e.g. the
>      server's TLS certificate is not trusted), the user agent must
>      terminate the connection (RFC 6797 section 8.4, Errors in Secure
>      Transport Establishment) and should not allow the user to access the
>      web application (section 12.1, No User Recourse).

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. I will see whether i can make all the pages https on my website.